# Limit as $n\to\infty$ of $n^\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$

Tags: limits, logarithms

I am trying to solve:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$

---

Here's what I did but I am not sure if it's right.

$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$
$$\implies\ln(S)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(n^\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln^2(n)}{n}$$

Applying L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\begin{align}
&\implies\ln(S)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\ln(n)}{n} \\
&\implies\ln(S)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n}=0 \\
&\implies S=1 \\
\end{align}$$

Is this correct and is this an ideal approach? Are there any better alternative approaches to this limit?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: This seems correct to me! One comment is you can compute the limit $\ln (n^{\frac{\ln n}{n}})$ without assuming the existence of $S$

Comment: I always write it with exponentials, but this looks to be correct!

Comment: It's correct if you already know the limit exists, otherwise you'd need to prove such an $S$ exists before finding it's value.

Comment: Alright thanks, but what would you do to make sure that the limit exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is fine. Here's another one just for fun, using the squeeze theorem.

---

The limit is clearly at least $1$. On the other hand, we have for $n$ sufficiently large (e.g. $n \ge 3$):

$$n^{\ln n / n} \le n^{\sqrt{n} / n} = n^{1/\sqrt{n}} = \left(\sqrt{n}^{1/\sqrt{n}}\right)^2.$$

Now using the well-known limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} t^{1/t} = 1$, the result follows.